# Python / BeautifulSoup - extract list <UL><LI> from between 2 headings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a website and their layout is basically this:

```
<h2>
    First Heading
</h2>
<h2>
    <span class="class" id="id1">Second Heading</span>
</h2>
<ul>
    <li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>Four</li><li>Five</li>
</ul>
<h2>
    <span class="class" id="id2">Third Heading</span>
</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Red</li><li>Orange</li><li>Yellow</li><li>Green</li><li>Blue</li>
</ul>
<h2>
    <span class="class" id="id3">Last Heading</span>
</h2>
<ul>
    <li>VVV</li><li>WWW</li><li>XXX</li><li>YYY</li><li>ZZZ</li>
</ul>
```

How do I go about getting the list items from between the Second Heading and Third Heading?

I started with this by considering something like this:

```
h2s = soup.find_all("h2")

for h2 in h2s:
    print(h2.span)
```

And then I moved on to something more like this:

```
startSpan = soup.find("span", id="id1")
stopSpan = soup.find("span", id="id2")
```

And thought about iterating through but am struggling to put this all together.

Ultimately what I am trying to get to is:

```
["One", "Two", "Three"...]
```

Without including the other lists further down the page.

Comment: If that is how the HTML is formatted, wouldn't `soup.find('ul')` work as expected in this situation? If there isn't anything before it, then that would just pull the first found `ul`

Comment: Looks like there is a `ul` before the content I need that I missed. So its actually the 2nd `ul` I need to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Search for the second `<h2>` tag using the [`:nth-of-type(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) CSS Selector.
2. Search for the next `<ul>` tag using the [`.find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print(
    soup.select_one("h2:nth-of-type(2)")
    .find_next("ul")
    .get_text(strip=True, separator="|")
    .split("|")
)
```

Output:

```
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
```

**Edit** to select all `<li>` tags under "Events":

```
for tag in soup.select(".mw-parser-output > ul:nth-of-type(1) li"):
    print(tag.text)
```

Comment: That definitely should work, and it does work on the example snippet I mentioned above.

What is going wrong in the real world such that I cannot get "Events"?

`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/December_31'
html = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one("h2:nth-of-type(1)"))
# Returns "Contents", the 1st header

print(soup.select_one("h2:nth-of-type(2)"))
# Returns "Births", the 3rd header
# One of those should return "Events" which is the one I care about`

Comment: @user15133383 This is based on the markup of the page. the easiest way is to copy the CSS Selector (In Chrome. `right-click -> Inspect -> Click on the element you want -> Right-click -> Copy -> Copy Selector`

Comment: @user15133383 I have edited my answer to select all elements under `Events`.